# Birt parameters

Tags: java, birt

I created a BIRT 4.3.0 report using the following code. The main point is: I want to pass a parameter `foo` to the dataSet:

```
public File actionPdf() throws EngineException {
    IReportEngine engine = getEngine();

    // Open the report design
    IReportRunnable design = null;
    design = engine.openReportDesign("c:\\hello_world.rptdesign");

    IRunAndRenderTask task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);
    task.setParameterValue("foo", "bar");
    task.validateParameters();

    PDFRenderOption PDF_OPTIONS = new PDFRenderOption();
    File f = new File("xyz.pdf");
    PDF_OPTIONS.setOutputFileName(f.getAbsolutePath());
    PDF_OPTIONS.setOutputFormat("pdf");

    task.setRenderOption(PDF_OPTIONS);

    task.run();
    task.close();
    return f;
}
```

and the dataSet looks as follows:

```
public class ActionsPerDateDataSet implements IPojoDataSet {

public void open(Object obj, Map<String,Object> map) {
    System.out.println( obj +  " map: " + map  + " size: " + map.size())    
}


2015-11-03T13:23:18.993+0100|Information {org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.util_consumerResourceIds=org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.util.ResourceIdentifiers@24a1f3df, org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.expression.compareHints=org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.expression.CompareHints@99fdef1, OdaConsumerId=org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile.connectionPropertyService, PDF_RENDER_CONTEXT=org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.PDFRenderContext@491c843} map: {} size: 0
```

But there is no parameter `foo` set.How can I get it?

Comment: Have you defined that parameter in your report? I'm not activtly using birt in the moment, so I answert from my mind. As I remember, a dataset has no parameters. A report can have parameters, which you can use in a dataset.

Comment: hm... my plan was to load data from the database using a parameter in the open method. Is this in general the correct approach?

Comment: I remember that I did alot with parameters. Changing datasources, creating queries etc. Look up the lifecycle of the report, there are several places where you can put ECMA Script to manipulate your report at generation time. So theoritcal your idea is right, as I understand it correct.

Answer (score 2):

From outside, you pass parameters *to the report*, not to the dataset.
You have to distinguish between report parameters and dataset parameters.
Inside the report, a dataset parameter *can* get its value from a report parameter, but this is not automatic. A dataset parameter could also get its value from the layout context (see the dataset parameter binding button in the properties).

See the BIRT documentation for details.

If you are coming from other report design tools, you may find this cumbersome and overly complicated, but in fact it is a great feature, because this allows reusing the same dataset several times within a report and is fundamental for reusing components by referencing them from libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define the parameter in the report Design.

[image: Creation of the parameter called masterbomid in your case it would be named as foo.]

[image: Assignment into a dataset used for the report it will take the value you send on the task.setParameterValue("foo", "bar");]